# SAS: Find Date of Last Day of Month Given Month and Year

Tags: date, calendar, sas

**Question:** Is there a way to find the date of the last day in a given month and year without using the first date of the month/year?

---

**My Solution**

The task I am working on requires both beginning and end dates to be assigned given only the month and year.  The solution I developed requires the begin date:

```
data assigndate;

    month = 12;
    year = 2011;

    begin_date = mdy(month, 01, year);
    end_date = intnx('month', begin_date, 0, 'end');

    format begin_date mmddyy8.;
    format end_date mmddyy8.;

run;
```

Of course, I could make it a one liner by substituting the expression for `begin_date` directly:

`end_date = intnx('month', mdy(month, 01, year), 0, 'end');`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the date format of YYMMN6. which is 201112 and doesn't include a date. I think using 1 as the day is easier though.

```
data want;
    month=12;
    year=2011;
    end_date=intnx('month', input(catt(year, month), yymmn6.) , 0, 'end');
    format end_date date9.;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works if you do not want to use "1".

```
data m;
  format end_date date9.;
  do year=1960 to 2022;
    do month=1 to 12;
      end_date = intnx('month', (year-1960)*365.25+(month*28), 0, 'end');
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;
```